# Embedded youtube-dl script not working anymore

Tags: python, youtube-dl

This code used to run perfectly but for some reason (maybe an update?) it isn't working anymore.

```
video_info = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL().extract_info(url = link['href'], download = False)
filename = f"{link['name']}.mp3"

path = f'{folder_path}/{filename}'

yt_options = {
            'format': 'bestaudio/best',
            'keepvideo': False,
            'outtmpl': path,
            'postprocessors': [{
                'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
                'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
                'preferredquality': '192'
            }]
        }

 with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(yt_options) as ydl:
            ydl.download([video_info['webpage_url']])
```

It used to work just fine but now I get this message:

```
ERROR: Unable to extract JS player URL; please report this issue on https://yt-dl.org/bug . Make sure you are using the latest version; see  https://yt-dl.org/update  on how to update. Be sure to call youtube-dl with the --verbose flag and include its complete output.
```

I've updated the the repo on my system but I can't get it to work..

Anyone knows that to do?

Comment: You should report it over their repo.  and/or see if there's a similar issue over there

Comment: Maybe it's because the repo is down mm..

Comment: oh, I just read

Comment: As they specify in their website "Currently our dev repository is taken down due to DMCA takedown notice by RIAA. " https://youtube-dl.org/